# getchar is printing extra output

Tags: c

```
root@ubuntu:~/DH$ cat E1-6.c 
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while(c = (getchar() != EOF)) {
        printf("HI: %d",c);
        //putchar(c);
    }
}
root@ubuntu:~/DH$ cc E1-6.c
root@ubuntu:~/DH$ ./a.out 
1
HI: 1HI: 1
```

I gave input as 1 using key board but in output it is displayed twice. Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: I am not able to understand why my output is printing twice?

Comment: So it is considering "ENTER" key also as input?

Comment: The second one is probably carriage return. I would recommend changing your code to `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`. That way `c` will store the actual character.

Comment: @davidbecker Yes, the ENTER key is another character just like any other.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings enabled. Clang reports `warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]` which is a good hint to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error happens because, as the comments noted, the "1" is a key and the "enter" press after the 1 (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for `EOF`) is another key.  As for why both are printing out "1", it is because you are setting `c` to be the boolean (true/false) value of `getchar() != EOF`.  What I think you want is

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

at the top if your loop.  That will save the pressed key into `c` and then check for EOF.

Comment: Good answer, but C doesn't have boolean type. All logical operations just return zero integer value in case of false and non zero interger value in case of true.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` statement isn't working correctly. Try running your program with the input "2", I think you will have an interesting result.

Your input is the character `1`, followed by a newline `\n`, and then EOF. The first call to `getchar` returns `1`, `1` is not `EOF`, so `c = 1`. The second call returns `\n`, `\n` is not `EOF`, so again `c = ('\n' != EOF)` which means `c = 1`.

Try instead:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
while(c = (getchar() != EOF)) {
```

should be

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

as `c` should be assigned not to the comparison but to the return value from `getchar`